# Python Selenium getting trading view URL of the snapshot

Tags: python, selenium, tradingview-api

I am trying to get the snapshot URL from the snapshot window that opens when ALT + S is pressed. I can save the image. but instead i want to get the URL that is in the snapshot box and save it in a variable

[image]

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC1
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Windows\\chromedriver.exe') # change as per your location
driver.get ("https://www.tradingview.com/chart/1pPtW0th/")
driver.maximize_window()
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.ALT).send_keys('s').perform()
wait_time = 25 # a very long wait time
#want to get snapshot URL here, instead of saving it.
element = WebDriverWait(driver, wait_time).until(EC1.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Save image')))[enter image description here][1]
time.sleep(3)
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try targeting the following `<div>` element and extract the attribute `"data-clipboard-text"`:

```html
<div data-clipboard-text="https://www.tradingview.com/x/ODEmfXoU/" class="copyBtn-1oB8tEqo- shadow-2JTdO0Fb-">
    <button class="button-2O-nMUcz- active-2UxWxOgk- withPadding-_5CJoO5q- ghost-3yO24wIn- primary-1rSzOFdX-" tabindex="0" title="" target="" href="">
        <span class="hiddenText-3qcN5Wif-">Copy</span>
        <span class="text-2KOWx3rB-">Copy</span>
    </button>
</div>
```